# Change picture on an ActiveX Commandbutton

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to change the picture on a CommandButton.

```
Sheets("Pallplatsmeny").OLEObjects("CommandButton2").Picture = "C:\users\Jens\Documents\Apoteket\Empty.gif"
```

Doesn't work.  What's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
.OLEObjects("CommandButton2").Object.Picture = LoadPicture("C:\users\Jens\Documents\Apoteket\Empty.gif")
```